# Extract the numerator and denominator of a nested fraction using sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to extract numerator and denominator of expression using sympy.fraction method.
The code is as follows-

```
from sympy import *
x=symbols('x')
a=1/(1+1/x)
print(fraction(a))
```

The output that I want is

> (x,x+1)

but it is outputting

> (1, 1+1/x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docstring of `fraction` says:

> This function will not make any attempt to simplify nested
>   fractions or to do any term rewriting at all.

The rewrite you want is done by `together`.

```
print(fraction(together(a)))   #  (x, x + 1)
```

`simplify` has the same effect, but it's a heavier tool that tries a lot of various simplification techniques. The output of specific functions like `together`, `cancel`, `factor`, etc is more predictable.

Comment: Why does the better answer get fewer votes in so many cases? :) I should have the documentation for simplify tattooed on my wrist: 'try to determine what you need exactly - is it powsimp()?, radsimp()?, together()?, logcombine()?, or something else?' Anyway, if I hadn't upvoted your answer no-one would have.

Answer (score 5):

Ask for simplification of the expression first:

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('x')
x
>>> a = 1/(1+1/x)
>>> a.simplify()
x/(x + 1)
>>> fraction(a.simplify())
(x, x + 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `as_numer_denom` method will recursively find the numerator and denominator of a rational expression:

```
>>> a.as_numer_denom()
(x, x + 1)
```

The functions `fraction`, `numer` and `denom` just give you the literal numerator and denominator of an expression without doing denesting.